# TinyMCE 2.1 on Bootstrap 3.3.5 video embed

Tags: video, youtube, tinymce, embed

My site is using Bootstrap with TinyMCE 2.1 for text editing and video publishing.

Here is my bootstrap.css after my edits:

```
.embed-responsive {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,
.embed-responsive iframe,
.embed-responsive embed,
.embed-responsive object,
.embed-responsive video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
.embed-responsive-16by9 {
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.embed-responsive-4by3 {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
```

My TinyMCE 2.1 pannel is always checked "Contrain proportions" even if you check out the box. Third tab looks like embed code which is hard to be edited

[image: TinyMCE First Tab]

[image: Third Tab]

What kind of code should I use in Bootstrap css and how do I implement it to the old tinyMCE?